# 'The pipe truncate could not be found'

Tags: angular, pipe

I have created a custom truncate pipe inside a shared folder(in app component) and the code is as follows:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, args: string[]): string {
  const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 10;
  const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';

  return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
 }
}
```

Declared the pipe in app.module.ts
Now, trying to use the pipe by importing it in some.component(in app component) as

```
<div class="content"><p>{{ element.description | truncate: 20}}</p></div>
```

which gives an error 'truncate pipe could not be found'

The module code is as follows:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
TruncatePipe,
..]
declarations: [
TruncatePipe,
..]
```

Comment: did you import it? import { TruncatePipe } from '..TruncatePipe.pipe';

Comment: yes, I have imported it as import { TruncatePipe } from '../shared/truncate.pipe'; Though it shows it is not being used(not highlighted)

Comment: Tried importing it in imports and declarations

Comment: and declare it ?
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TruncatePipe
    ...
  ],

Comment: Can you show your module code here?

Comment: imports: [ TruncatePipe]
declarations: [TruncatePipe]

Comment: The whole thing, I mean.  Edit it into the question.

Comment: I don't THINK you need it in the imports. Somebody correct me if wrong. But you do need an import statement at the top.

Comment: Assuming you only have the one module, you only need to add it to `declarations` and not `imports`.

Comment: Just threw your pipe into a demo project, added it to `app.module` declarations and it started working. Side note, you need to change your pipe `transform` method to be `...args: string[]` to get it to work.

Comment: Tried both ways, added only to declarations, still the same

Comment: @SimonK Can you be more specific? It was already transform(value: string, args: string[])

Comment: remove `TruncatePipe ` from your `imports` in your `@NgModule`.

Comment: Otherwise, you put your pipe in `imports`, it would be an error in compile.
`Unexpected pipe 'TruncatePipe' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.` 
But the error msg only show the pipe was not found, I think yours have duplicate files or the same `NgModule` to overwrite previous which you had modified.

Comment: Notice the `...` where I wrote `...args: string[]`, that will compile all of the args into a single array else your `args` will just be the first arg and not an array.